# set up android studio

Tags: android, memory, gradle

Help please can't set up Android studio 1.4 to work properly on my pc. Been on it for about a week now, and it's frustrating. Some errors I get:

```
9:21:34 PM Gradle sync started
9:21:38 PM Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
           This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
           For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
           Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
           Please read the following process output to find out more:
           -----------------------
           Error occurred during initialization of VM
           Could not reserve enough space for object heap
           Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
           Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Here's what my screen looks like

[screen shot after launching a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVW0D.png)

I have installed all the marked options from Android SDK Manager, yet it's still not working. Always launch with the "run as administration" option, and have tried launching while offline and online. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wiil not have enough free memory on your computer.

**Remember** you gonna have a problem if you didn't have at least 1GB of free memory

Run Android Studio as Administrator:

1. Go to File and press Settings (or use shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. Go to Compiler
3. Find VM Options and put -Xmx512m.
4. Press Apply
5. Press OK
6. restart IDE

Comment: I haven't even got to the stage of developing any app. I can't even drag and drop buttons in design mode - can't edit anything.